# Junit Matcher for comparators?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest, matcher

For several days I am using now Junit's Matchers feature. Everything is working OK but I am looking for a matcher which uses a comparator for comparing and which does not rely on the objects equals methodes.

I want to replace

```
Assert.assertThat(one, CoreMatchers.equalTo(two)
```

with something like (pseudocode)

```
Assert.assertThat(eins, CoreMatchers.equalTo(operand, new MyComparator())
```

Do you know whether there exists an easy out of the box solution? I did not find one in google and do not want to write one.

Comment: You can try to write your own matcher, extending [BaseMatcher](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.9/org/hamcrest/BaseMatcher.html).

Comment: Surprised it doesn't exist. Please post your solution so next person could use it.

Answer (score 15):

This is now supported in Hamcrest 2.0.0.0+.

You can use the [org.hamcrest.comparator.ComparatorMatcherBuilder](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.0.0.0/org/hamcrest/comparator/ComparatorMatcherBuilder.html) class to achieve this, for instance:

```
ComparatorMatcherBuilder builder = ComparatorMatcherBuilder.comparedBy(equivalenceComparator);
Assert.assertThat(eins, builder.comparesEqualTo(operand));
```

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: Corrected dead link

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in hamcrest 1.3 and solved it by writing a matcher, that follows the code of the IsEqual-Matcher but uses a given Comparator instead of Object#equals().

```
import org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher;
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Factory;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.junit.Assert;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * Is the value equal to another value, as tested by the
 * given Comparator?<br/>
 * Based on the example of {@link org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual}.
 *
 * @author Serhat Cinar
 */
public class IsEqualWithComparator<T> extends BaseMatcher<T> {
    private final Object expectedValue;
    private final Comparator<T> comparator;

    public IsEqualWithComparator(T equalArg, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        expectedValue = equalArg;
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object actualValue) {
        return areEqual(actualValue, expectedValue, comparator);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendValue(expectedValue);
    }

    private static boolean areEqual(Object actual, Object expected, Comparator comparator) {
        if (actual == null) {
            return expected == null;
        }

        if (expected != null && isArray(actual)) {
            return isArray(expected) && areArraysEqual(actual, expected, comparator);
        }

        return comparator.compare(actual, expected) == 0;
    }

    private static boolean areArraysEqual(Object actualArray, Object expectedArray, Comparator comparator) {
        return areArrayLengthsEqual(actualArray, expectedArray) && areArrayElementsEqual(actualArray, expectedArray, comparator);
    }

    private static boolean areArrayLengthsEqual(Object actualArray, Object expectedArray) {
        return Array.getLength(actualArray) == Array.getLength(expectedArray);
    }

    private static boolean areArrayElementsEqual(Object actualArray, Object expectedArray, Comparator comparator) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(actualArray); i++) {
            if (!areEqual(Array.get(actualArray, i), Array.get(expectedArray, i), comparator)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isArray(Object o) {
        return o.getClass().isArray();
    }

    @Factory
    public static <T> Matcher<T> equalTo(T operand, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        return new IsEqualWithComparator<>(operand, comparator);
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        Assert.assertThat("abc", IsEqualWithComparator.equalTo("ABC", new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.equalsIgnoreCase(o2) ? 0 : -1;
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one option is using [AspectJ framework custom comparison strategy](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#custom-comparison-strategy) for object and iterables.

```
assertThat(frodo).usingComparator(raceComparator).isEqualTo(sam);
assertThat(fellowshipOfTheRing).usingElementComparator(raceComparator).contains(sauron);
```

It has also [Field by field comparisons](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#field-by-field-comparison), e.g. [isEqualToComparingOnlyGivenFields](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#field-by-field-ignoring) and [isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#field-by-field-ignoring) comparators.

```
assertThat(frodo).isEqualToComparingOnlyGivenFields(sam, "race.name");
assertThat(frodo).isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(sam, "name", "age");
```

So, in most case, you can handle assertion without custom comparison strategy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything in Hamcrest to do that. You may need to write a custom matcher. One thing to consider: if `equals` is not returning `true`, are the objects equal? If you're testing for specific properties, your custom matcher may be clearer as a [`FeatureMatcher`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/FeatureMatcher.html) ([Is there a simple way to match a field using Hamcrest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033526/is-there-a-simple-way-to-match-a-field-using-hamcrest)). For example, if the test is for an expected label:

```
assertThat(eins, equalToUnderComparison("1", new LabelComparator());
```

may be clearer as:

```
assertThat(eins, hasLabel(eq("1")));
```

Writing custom matchers doesn't take a lot of code ([Writing custom matchers](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial#Writing_custom_matchers)) and there's no reason to avoid it if it makes code more readable.

Comment: It's very actual for JPA model instances where you cannot implement equals/hashCode, based on business logic. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031614/the-jpa-hashcode-equals-dilemma

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon the same use case with `verify()` method. Decided to implement a custom `ArgumentMatcher` that simply copies all uninterested class properties before comparing them.

```
verify(testService).save(eqIgnoreA(saved));

public static Foo eqIgnoreA(Foo expected) {
  return argThat(actual -> {
    actual.setA(expected.getA());
    return expected.equals(actual);
  });
}
```