# Junit assertEquals on objects with double fields

Tags: junit, double-precision

I have two Lists of Objects.  These objects reference other objects which in turn contain doubles.  I want to use assertEquals to test that the two objects are the same.  I have verified by hand that they are, but assertEquals is still returning false.  I think the reason is because the doubles are not the same because of precision issues.  I know that I can solve this problem by drilling down to the double fields and using assertEquals(d1, d2, delta), but that seems cumbersome.  Is there anyway to provide a delta to assertEquals (or another method), such that it can use that delta whenever it encounters doubles to compare?

Answer (score 0):

[Hamcrest matchers](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial) may make this a little easier. You can create a custom `Matcher` (or a `FeatureMatcher` - [Is there a simple way to match a field using Hamcrest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033526/is-there-a-simple-way-to-match-a-field-using-hamcrest)), then compose it with a [`closeTo`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#closeTo%28double,%20double%29) to test for doubles, and then use container matchers ([How do I assert an Iterable contains elements with a certain property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166415/how-do-i-assert-a-list-contains-elements-with-a-certain-property)) to check the list.

For example, to check for a list containing exactly one `Thing`, which has a `getValue` method returning approximately `10`:

```
Matcher<Thing> thingWithExpectedDouble =
    Matchers.<Thing>hasProperty("value", Matchers.closeTo(10, 0.0001));
assertThat(listOfItems, Matchers.contains(thingWithExpectedDouble));
```