# Creating custom asserts/matchers for domain types with JUnit and Hamcrest

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, junit

I have an entity in my domain named Order. It has properties such as `dateOfOrder`, `status`, `orderItems` etc.

In my tests I need to be sure that all properties have been set. Currently I write a lot of asserts to be sure that all properties have been set.

```
assertEqual(4, order.getId());
...
```

However I would like to create my own assertion for an order (and other kinds of domain objects) like this:

```
assertEqual(myExpectedOrder, order);
```

I have been looking at writing custom matchers etc. But I don't know if they are the right thing to use. I don't want the custom assertion in a method, I want to have separate assertion classes such as `OrderAssert` or `OrderMatcher` - whatever is the correct thing to use.

What should I use and how? I want to check that all the attributes contain the expected values.

Comment: Overriding equals is not an option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way to match a field using Hamcrest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033526/is-there-a-simple-way-to-match-a-field-using-hamcrest)